# How can I split raw DV files captured by Kino?

Tags: lubuntu, avconv, capture, firewire

I tried using avconv but it throws an error, and I'm not sure what it's telling me:

```
techmachine@techmachine:/media/techmachine/Backup$ sudo avconv -i video.dv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 1:37:35 output.dv
avconv version 9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Aug 10 2014 18:19:26 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[dv @ 0x840b4e0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, dv, from 'video.dv':
  Duration: 03:23:06.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28771 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: dvvideo, yuv411p, 720x480, 28771 kb/s, PAR 8:9 DAR 4:3, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s
    Stream #0.2: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s
[dv @ 0x8412ac0] Can't initialize DV format!
Make sure that you supply exactly two streams:
     video: 25fps or 29.97fps, audio: 2ch/48kHz/PCM
     (50Mbps allows an optional second audio stream)
Output #0, dv, to 'output.dv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0: Video: dvvideo, yuv411p, 720x480 [PAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 28771 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, stereo, 1024 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
```

Can someone help me either use a diff program to split the DV file, or maybe help with the avconv command?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but this works for me:

```
~$ avconv -i /home/bill/Videos/Editing/03-a.dv -ss 100 -t 100  copy /home/bill/aa1.dv
```

This created a section small `dv` file starting at 100 seconds and of 100 seconds duration.